# db transaction in golang

Tags: database, transactions, go

In Java, it's pretty easy to switch between auto commit and manual commit of a database transaction. When I say easy, I mean it doesn't need to change the connection interface. Simply setAutoCommit to be true or false will switch the transaction between auto/manual mode. However, Go uses different connection interface, sql.DB for auto mode, and sql.Tx for manual mode. It's not a problem for a one off use. The problem is I have a framework which uses sql.DB to do the db work, now I want some of them to join my new transaction, and it seems to be not that easy without modifying the existing framework to accept sql.Tx. I am wondering if there is really not an easy way to do the auto/manual switch in Go?

Comment: @rightføld, I don't think what I wrote to compare with Java is irrelevant. That is what I hope it to be. Should I modify other people's post, at least I would get approval from the authoritative owner of the post.

Comment: "a framework" - what framework is that? Knowing that would help in finding an answer. Or is it a framework you wrote  yourself?

Comment: @ElgsQianChen From the Stack Overflow documentation (http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing): "If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you."

Comment: @rob74 yes, it is my home made framework.

Comment: @Topo I love Stackoverflow, but this is the only thing I hate it.

Comment: @Topo I read your link, it said like this: To fix grammar and spelling mistakes To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning) To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages To add related resources or hyperlinks. What rightføld did was she/he removed part of my post which has important meaning.

Answer (score 6):

Without knowing more about which framework you are using, I don't think there is a way to do it without modifying the framework. You should really try to get the modifications you do included in the framework because the main problem here is that the framework you are using is designed poorly. When writing for a new language (specially a library or framework) you should get to know the conventions and design your software accordingly.

In go, it is not to hard to accomplish this functionality you just have to declared the `Queryer` (or however you want to call it) interface like this:

```
type Queryer interface {
    Query(string, ...interface{}) (*sql.Rows, error)
    QueryRow(string, ...interface{}) *sql.Row
    Prepare(string) (*sql.Stmt, error)
    Exec(string, ...interface{}) (sql.Result, error)
}
```

This interface is implemented implicitly by the `sql.DB` and the `sql.Tx` so after declaring it, you just have to modify the functions/methods to accept the `Queryer` type instead of a `sql.DB`.

Comment: I'm passing my connections (*sql.DB) around, in Java, I can let the client decide if they'd like to join a transaction or not, but in go, it seems to be impossible, because if the client decide to join a transaction, they have to use *sql.Tx instead of *sql.DB, thus, my interface breaks.

Comment: @ElgsQianChen I don't understand why the interface breaks. With this interface you can pass both (Tx and DB) to a function or method and it just works, but maybe I'm not understanding your point.

Comment: Thanks @Topo, I ended up passing both Tx and DB to my function. It works, but looks not that elegant.

Comment: @ElgsQianChen you are welcome. But for the sake of having the complete answer, could you explain why the interface doesn't work for you?

Comment: When I talked about my interface broke, I meant the case when I passed in only `*sql.DB`. It seems in Go, a DB can only start a Tx, but cannot join a Tx, and be part of a transaction by passing the DB around. That is what I do a lot in Java. My old interface has only DB as parameter, so it didn't work with transactions, thus, it was broken. Now by adopting advice from @Topo, I pass both DB and Tx around, and probably a flag indicating to use the DB or the Tx, I can do pretty much the same thing again. It's just it's a little bit ugly.